# Submit n forms With one button MVC .NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a page that has 2 or more partial views rendered within it. Each of the views is a form that is submittable. The supplied models for the views are submitted from the `MyProject.Models.CompositeModel` that holds an object and a list of objects (both objects are ADO.NET Models, Lets call them Model_1 and Model_2).

The 2+ models that are rendered to the partial views have properties with the same name, and the inputs also have the same name (both in the fact that model_2 form can have n iterations, and that the 2 models them selves have some properties with the same names).

I render the parent view as such:

```
@model MyProject.Models.CompositeModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>

@Html.Partial("_Table1EditRowPartial",Model.Table1RowData)
@foreach (var Table2RowData in Model.Table2Rows) { 
    @Html.Partial("_Table2EditRowPartial",Table2RowData)
}
```

... and the partial views are:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Model_x

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prop_1)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prop_1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prop_1)

    ...

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prop_n)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prop_n)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prop_n)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

I need a way to submit either all forms asynchronously via either jQuery or the .NET ajax helper lib. Alternatively if I can have a button that takes the models divided and edited, and then reassembles it into the `CompositModel` and submits it. It could be in Razor syntax or whatever else, any one method do fine, and if  there's a built in way I would prefer to do it that way rather then expanding my lib database.

Comment: Why you just wrapped all in one form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than dividing them into separate forms and recombining them, why not just create 1 well formatted form to submit? Welcome to the magical world of `EditorTemplates`!

### 1. Create an EditorTemplate

Create an editor template in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Model_x.cshtml` or `[parent_root]/EditorTemplates/Model_x.cshtml`

It will look something like this.

```
@model MyProject.Models.Model_x

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.prop_1)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.prop_1)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prop_1)

...

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.prop_n)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.prop_n)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prop_n)
```

### 2. Use the editor template in your view.

They will replace your use of partials (which do not work well for forms) and will look something like this.

```
@model MyProject.Models.CompositeModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Table1RowData)
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Table2Rows.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Table2Rows[i])
    }
    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
}
```

### 3. Success!

When you post the form, you should have a complete model `MyProject.Models.CompositeModel` filled in.